# Problemas Al Iniciar Sesion conexion php mysql

Tags: php, html5, hosting

Hola Tengo Un Problema no puedo lograr iniciar sesion y no me muestra en pantalla error en X o Y columna solo me tira el mensaje prediseñado en caso que falle aqui el codigo (ayuda urgente porfavor es un trabajo que quiero presentar en el colegio)

```
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db,$user_db,$pass_db,$db_name);
if($conexion->connect_error){
    die("Algo Ah Fallado:".$conexion->connection_error);
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['clave'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Usuario = '$username'";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows === 1){
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(password_verify($password,$row['Password'])){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] =true;
            $_SESSION['Usuario'] =$username;
            $_SESSION['start'] =time();
            $_SESSION['expire'] =$_SESSION['start']+(5*60);
            header('Location: index.php');
            }else{
                echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, Ya te haz registrado.?";
                echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";

                }
        }
```

Comment: osea el mensaje que me dice es: Usuario o Contraseña Icorrectos, Ya te haz registrado, cuando eh escrito bien todo siempre sale :(

Comment: por qué pusiste una etiqueta "hosting"? tienes ese archivo en algún hosting web y no te funciona? Podrías mostrar el código con el que haces la conexión a la base de datos?

Comment: Pero entonces si te conecta a la DB, el problema has de tenerlo en **if(password_verify($password,$row['Password']))** ya que te salta al else.
Haz que te imprima en pantalla los valores **$password** y **$row['Password']** y comprueba que se esten pasando correctamente. Si son correctos revisa la funcion **password_verify**

Comment: si tengo la etiqueta hosting por que necesito subirlo a uno y hacer un login desde ahi :( al registrarme me funciona perfectamente y dentro despues del login tengo otro form de enviar informacion que tambien me funciona bien solo es ese codigo de login que no me funciona no se por que se salta hasta el else, intentare eso que me dices grax.

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo este es el codigo que sesupone me permite la conexion me ha servido en otros pero en este no   
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db,$user_db,$pass_db,$db_name);
if($conexion->connect_error){
 die("Algo Ah Fallado:".$conexion->connection_error);
 }

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código que usas para ingresar usuarios a la db?

Answer (score 1):

Según el manual, [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php),  necesita como primer parámetro, tu password como tal, es decir, `$password` en tu caso, y como segundo parámetro, esa misma password pero 'hasheada', por así españolizarlo.

Entonces el problema puede ser que el segundo parámetro que pones en password_verify() puede estar no 'hasheado'. Debes verificar en la db, si las password están 'hasheadas' o no. O bien, si cuando un usuario se registra, su password se ingresa 'hasheada'.

Cómo hasheas la password para ingresarla a la db? Usando [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php), lo cual deberías implementar cuando un usuario se registra y establece su password.

Este es tu código probado con parámetros fijos y 'hasheando' la password traída de la db antes de usar el password_verify(). Por supuesto es solo a modo demostrativo, pues lo correcto es que la password venga ya 'hasheada' desde la db.

```
<?php 
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
if($conexion->connect_error){
  die("Algo Ah Fallado:".$conexion->connection_error);
  }
  $username = 'roberto';
  $password = '123456';
  $tbl_name = 'usuarios';  //no pusiste de dónde venía este dato en tu ejemplo, solo lo construí aquí para testear.
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Usuario = '$username'";
  $result = $conexion->query($sql);
  if($result->num_rows === 1){
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $hasheada = password_hash($row['Password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  //hasheo la password con el método por defecto. Recuerda que es solo para ejemplificar lo que te falta.
    if(password_verify($password,$hasheada)){
      $_SESSION['loggedin'] =true;
      $_SESSION['Usuario'] =$username;
      $_SESSION['start'] =time();
      $_SESSION['expire'] =$_SESSION['start']+(5*60);
      //header('Location: index.html');
      echo $hasheada;  //comenté el header solo para ver la password hasheada.
    }
    else{
      echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos, Ya te haz registrado.?";
      echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Lo que se muestra en pantalla es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que corresponde a '123456' hasheado.

**nota1:**
 Esta respuesta la he investigado y probado recién ahora, es decir, no tengo experiencia en el tema, solo estoy suponiendo que tal vez el error corresponde a lo que propongo. En cualquier caso, podría servir para alguien que si haya cometido ese error.

**nota2**
El término 'hash' no tengo claro si es lo mismo que 'encriptar', por eso no he usado este último. Si alguien que lo sepa pudiera corroborarlo, sería de gran ayuda para desespañolizar el 'hasheando', 'hasheado', 'hasheada' que usé en esta respuesta.

Comment: grax men me ayudaste :D

Comment: que bien, entonces solucionaste el inconveniente?

Comment: si, te agradesco por cierto.